# Page refresh after reset values

Tags: typescript

I made a user role management page in which I show for every user if he can or can't access in a section of a website. Every user has default privileges and I create a Reset button to restore the original values. I write the code below and it works, because in my DB I can see the values updated, but I don't know how to refresh the page to see in real time what happened.

```
let ResetUserPermission = document.getElementById("btn-reset-ruoli");
    if (ResetUserPermission)
        ResetUserPermission.addEventListener("click", async ev => {
            ev.preventDefault();

            SwalWrapper.fire({
                type: "question",
                title: "Do you want to restore the default values?",
                showCancelButton: true

            }).promise.then(result => {
                if (result) {
                    console.log("You clicked OK");
                    let menu = [];
                    let tab = [];
                    let func = [];

                    var val = $("#user").val();
                    $(".combomenu").each(function () {

                        menu.push($(this).val());
                    })
                    $(".combotab").each(function () {

                        tab.push($(this).val());
                    })
                    $(".combofunc").each(function () {

                        func.push($(this).val());
                    })
                    console.log("Acquired Values")
                    const data = {
                        IdUser: val,
                        IdMenu: menu,
                        IdTab: tab,
                        IdFunzione: func
                    };

                    try {
                        Core.compatibility.fetch("/RolesManagement/ResetUserPermission", {

                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify(data)
                        }).then(response => {
                            if (!response.ok) {
                                throw new Error(response.statusText);
                            } else {
                                SwalWrapper.fire({
                                    type: "success",
                                    title: "Reset done"
                                });
                                getPermessi();
                                console.log("getPermessi() executed")
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (e) {
                        SwalWrapper.fire({
                            type: "error",
                            title: "Errore",
                            text: e
                        });
                    };
                    window.location.reload();
                    console.log("Page reloaded");
                }
            })

            
        });
```

getPermessi():

```
    export function getPermessi() {
    let menu = [];
    let tab = [];
    let func = [];
    var val = $("#Username").val();
    $(".combomenu").each(function () {

        menu.push($(this).val());
    })
    $(".combotab").each(function () {

        tab.push($(this).val());
    })
    $(".combofunc").each(function () {

        func.push($(this).val());
    })
}
```

I debugged my code and I've seen it stops before the `window.location.reload();` instruction and I don't know why. So, how can I reload my page after the reset?